# How to check whether data is being overfiited for that model in weka

Tags: classification, weka

my original dataset has 500 instances 10 classes and class imbalance is present

in order to reduce class imbalance i used the oversampling techinque and my 
new datset has 1500 instances and 10 classes.

for original dataset  i have applied j48 classifier and got 63% accuracy

for new sampled datset  i have applied j48 classifier and got 75% accuracy.

My question is i have a doubt that my data is overfitted for the classifier.

How to check whether the data is overfitted and how to reduce the overfitting

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one would talk about a classifier being overfit to data and not the other way round. It means that a classifier (such as a decision tree in your case) doesn't learn the general concept behind the data, but merely to approximate the peculiarities of the data.

To check whether your classifier overfits, you need separate train and test sets. The original and the oversampled data in your case won't do -- you need data that is completely separate, i.e. no overlapping points. Weka has various options to achieve that -- you can tell it what the train/test split should be, use an explicit test set given in another file or cross-validation.

Once you have the separate sets, you would train your classifier on your training set and evaluate it on your test set. You get accuracies on both sets and if they are very unbalanced (e.g. 90% accuracy on the training set but only 50% on the test set), this would be an indication of overfitting. Note that there are no hard rules though, in the end it is all down to your judgment.

Comment: By adjusting the parameters of the algorithm, e.g. for `J48` you could try increasing the number of instances required at each leaf.

Answer (score 0):

AS mentioned by Lars in his answer, its not clear whether your classifier is suffering from overfitting on the test data, or is under-trained. Your problem sounds like the latter case to me.

Also, when working with unbalanced data it's also important to check that the test/training accuracy is equally good on all classes, since your classifier might have a "bias" toward high accuracy on some classes, but very poor accuracy on others.

Comment: actually my question is how to know whether the classifier is overfitted